# Why UFDC-1 only returns FF on i2c communication?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, i2c

I'm currently working to measure the frequency of a squared wave signal and to do so i have identified the UFDC-1 IC.

I've built a prototype on breadboard using an arduino uno R3 as a microcontroller to read out the data outputted by the ic as follow:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define UFDC1_ADDRESS 0x77 

void setup() {
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  byte registerAddress = 0x01;

  Wire.beginTransmission(UFDC1_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(registerAddress);

  int result = Wire.endTransmission();
  if (result != 0) {
    Serial.println("Write failed");
  }

  Wire.beginTransmission(UFDC1_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(registerAddress);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(UFDC1_ADDRESS, 1);
  if (Wire.available()) {
    byte readValue = Wire.read();
    Serial.print("Read: ");
    Serial.println(readValue, HEX);
  }
  
  delay(1000); 
}
```

Address and registers to read are as for datasheet, as well as the circuit, built in the exact same way.

Nonetheless the ic only outputs 0xFF, regardless of the register/function selected.

Comment: FF is the idle state of the i2c bus, so it seems more likely to me that your IC just isn't set up properly and isn't repsonding to messages. Are you sure you have the address right, including the R/W bit?

Comment: @Hearth I believe it is responding, because changing the address to a random one it stops sending back FF.

Comment: Based on pinout, UFDC-1 is literally a pre-programmed AVR, maybe ATMega328. Your Arduino is also an ATMega328. Why do you need two MCUs if you could simply measure the square wave on identical hardware on your Arduino? That aside, the UFDC-1 I2C protocol is poorly documented in the data sheet. Not an answer but likely Arduino already has libraries for measuring frequency of a square wave signal.